# Discord API error when trying to send one command at discord using JavaScript client

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm working on a discord bot and I have started to have an error constantly. The console log shows me this:

```
2020-09-19T15:19:46.303295+00:00 app[worker.1]: embed.fields[7].value: Could not interpret "{'status': 'online', 'game': {'name': 'pp!help | Connected to 17 servers and 1087 users!', 'type': 1, 'url': 'https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=35XFAkwmU4c'}}" as string.
2020-09-19T15:19:46.303297+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at /app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/rest/RequestHandlers/Sequential.js:68:65
2020-09-19T15:19:46.303299+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at /app/node_modules/snekfetch/src/index.js:215:21
2020-09-19T15:19:46.303300+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
2020-09-19T15:19:46.303435+00:00 app[worker.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
2020-09-19T15:19:46.303522+00:00 app[worker.1]: (node:4) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code
```

In theory, the error is at this code on my bot.js but I can't find it:

```
client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`Listo, con ${client.users.size} usuarios, en ${client.channels.size} canales de ${client.guilds.size} servidores.`);
  client.user.setPresence(
      {
       status: "online", 
       game: { 
         name: `pp!help | Connected to ${client.guilds.size} servers and ${client.users.size} users!`, 
         url: `https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=35XFAkwmU4c`, // Establece el enlace del juego si el tipo es "STREAMING".
         type: "STREAMING"
       }
    }
  );

});
```

That error appears when I try to run the next command:

```
 const Discord = require('discord.js');
 const client = new Discord.Client();
function checkDays(date) {
         let now = new Date();
         let diff = now.getTime() - date.getTime();
         let days = Math.floor(diff / 86400000);
         return days + (days == 1 ? " day" : " days") + " ago";
};
     let inline = true
     
     let userinfo = {};
    userinfo.bot = message.client.user.bot;
    userinfo.createdat = message.client.user.createdAt;
    userinfo.discrim = message.client.user.discriminator;
    userinfo.id = message.client.user.id;
    userinfo.mfa = message.client.user.mfaEnabled;
    userinfo.pre = message.client.user.premium;
    userinfo.presen = message.client.user.presence;
    userinfo.tag = message.client.user.tag;
    userinfo.uname = message.client.user.username;
    userinfo.verified = message.client.user.verified;

    userinfo.avatar = message.client.user.avatarURL;
   
     const status = {
        false: "No",
        true: "Yes"
      }
 
    
    message.channel.send({embed: {
      color: 3447003,
      author: {
          name: userinfo.uname
      },
      title: userinfo.uname,
      description: "Info about this user",
      fields: [{
          name: "BOT?",
          value: userinfo.bot, inline 
        },
               {
          name: "Name",
          value: userinfo.uname, inline
        },
        {
          name: "Discriminator",
          value: `#${userinfo.discrim}`, inline
         },
         {
           name: "Client ID",
           value: userinfo.id, inline
         },
         {
           name: "2FA?",
          value: userinfo.mfa, inline
        }, 
        {
          name: "It paid?",
          value: userinfo.pre, inline
        },
        {
          name: "Created at",
          value: userinfo.createdat, inline
        },
        {
          name: "Presence",
          value: userinfo.presen, inline
        }
      ],
      timestamp: new Date(),
      
    }
});
    
}
```

If someone can say to me what does that log fail means or something I will be very thanked.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`client.user.presence` returns a [`Presence`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Presence), a very complex object. I believe you are looking for [`Presence#status`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Presence?scrollTo=status), which will return `online`, `offline`, `idle`, or `dnd`

```js
userinfo.presen = message.client.user.presence.status;
```

---

Also, instead of adding every property to the `userinfo` object after it's been defined, you could condense your code using object destructuring:

```js
// change:
let userinfo = {};
userinfo.bot = message.client.user.bot;
userinfo.createdat = message.client.user.createdAt;
userinfo.discrim = message.client.user.discriminator;
userinfo.id = message.client.user.id;
userinfo.mfa = message.client.user.mfaEnabled;
userinfo.pre = message.client.user.premium;
userinfo.presen = message.client.user.presence.status;
userinfo.tag = message.client.user.tag;
userinfo.uname = message.client.user.username;
userinfo.verified = message.client.user.verified;
userinfo.avatar = message.client.user.avatarURL;

// to:
const {
 bot,
 createdAt,
 discriminator,
 id,
 mfaEnabled, // if you want to create an alias, you could write `mfaEnabled: alias`
 premium,
 presence: { status },
 tag,
 username,
 verified,
 avatarURL,
} = message.client.user;

console.log(username) // same as `message.client.user.username`, but way shorter!
```

```js
data = {
  id: '38xY8',
  numbers: {
    number1: 1,
    number2: 2,
    number3: 3,
    number4: 4,
    number5: 5,
  },
};

let numberinfo = {};
numberinfo.one = data.numbers.number1;
numberinfo.two = data.numbers.number2;
numberinfo.three = data.numbers.number3;
numberinfo.four = data.numbers.number4;
numberinfo.five = data.numbers.number5;

console.log(numberinfo.four);
```

```js
data = {
  id: '38xY8',
  numbers: {
    number1: 1,
    number2: 2,
    number3: 3,
    number4: 4,
    number5: 5,
  },
};

let {
  number1: one,
  number2: two,
  number3: three,
  number4: four,
  number5: five
} = data.numbers;

console.log(four);
```

Comment: I owe you bro... Thanks @Lioness100 (Lo I don't know how overflow works xd)